# How to get file size in MultipartStreamProvider GetStream when missing from ContentDisposition

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

I creating a custom MultipartStreamProvider to store files in Azure File Storage as part of a Lift & Shift effort of a legacy application.  The client is using AngularJS on the front end and WebAPI on the backend. When I am trying to use the MultipartStreamProvider, I need to implement GetStream to return a stream for it to write to. I am using cloudFile.OpenWrite which asks for the size of the stream/file that will be written to it. However, in GetStream, the ContentDisposition.Size is empty. Is there a way I can either make the AngularJS send the content size for each file or on the backend, maybe I can dig the size of the file stream from somewhere else?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**MultipartStreamProvider**

```
        public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        // For form data, Content-Disposition header is a requirement
         ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = headers.ContentDisposition;

        Console.WriteLine(files.Count);
        if (contentDisposition != null)
        {
            // create default filename if its missing
            contentDisposition.FileName = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName) ? $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.data" : contentDisposition.FileName);

            // We won't post process files as form data
            _isFormData.Add(false);

            CloudMultipartFileData fileData = new CloudMultipartFileData(headers, _fileRepository.BaseUrl, contentDisposition.FileName);// your - aws - filelocation - url - maybe);
            _fileData.Add(fileData);

            var azureStream = _fileRepository.GetWriteStream(contentDisposition.Size, _relativeDirectory, fileData.FileName);

            return azureStream;

            // We will post process this as form data
            _isFormData.Add(true);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Did not find required 'Content-Disposition' header field in MIME multipart body part..");
    }
```

**Actual Call to Azure**

```
        public override Stream GetWriteStream(long? fileSize, string relativeDirectory, string filename)
    {
        var combinedRelativeDirectory = GetCloudDirectory(relativeDirectory);
        CloudFile cloudFile = combinedRelativeDirectory.GetFileReference(filename);
        return cloudFile.OpenWrite(fileSize, null, null);
    }
```

**AngularJS File Upload Code**

```
        /********************************** Add/Upload Photos **************************************/
    $scope.$watch('files', function (files) {
        $scope.formUpload = false;
        console.log(files);
        if (files != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                $scope.errorMsg = null;
                (function (file) {
                    upload(file);
                })(files[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    function upload(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: window.location.origin + "/api/mydocs/uploadfile?storeFolder=" + $scope.attachmentFolder + "&storeId=" + $scope.storeId + "&userId=" + $scope.currentUser.UserId,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {},
            fields: {},
            file: file

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up manually adding the file size to the header

```
        function upload(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: window.location.origin + "/api/mydocs/uploadfile?storeFolder=" + $scope.myFolder + "&clientId=" + $scope.clientId,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'file-info':file.name + "-/" + file.size },
            fields: {},
            file: file

        });
```

And then in the constructor, I use that to create a lookup table:

```
    public MyCloudMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string relativeDirectory, IEnumerable<string> lookupInfo)
    {
        NewFileNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        _fileRepository = new CloudFileRepository();
        _relativeDirectory = relativeDirectory;
        _uploadedFilesLookup = new Dictionary<string, long>();
        foreach (var fileInfo in lookupInfo)
        {
            var values = Regex.Split(fileInfo, @"-/");
            _uploadedFilesLookup.Add(values[0], Int64.Parse(values[1]));
        }
    }
```

Then grab the file's size out of the lookup table and pass that to my GetWriteStream method

```
            var azureStream = _fileFacade.GetWriteStream(_uploadedFilesLookup[fileName], 
                _relativeDirectory, fileData.FileName, out newFileName);
```